# I don't understand, why people are downvoting my questions?

Tags: discussion

This website is made for asking, it was meant for asking. So when a beginner comes to ask something the community should be proud to have someone new that wants to learn something. Asking doesn't mean that you're stupid, it means that you're willing to learn something.

But instead of this they downvote the simple questions like only pro questions are allowed here. Many of them believe that everyone is a master or everyone knows how to search over the internet for an answer. Well then I wonder why is this site even here if that's the whole point. Maybe we beginners should go on reddit, at least there people are respecting each other much more than here.

I'm just saying that is a shame to be such kind of a person, I'm sure that your programming is just as bad as your respect for the others around here. I'm pretty sure this will get many downvotes, I don't care about it, that was my point. Now go on, downvote and show us how smart you the "pros" are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a good point here, which I try to remind folks of quite frequently. When you're really new to something, *you don't always know what to search for*. That's easy to lose track of as you get better at something.

It's always good to indicate this in your question, e.g.

> I have been frustratingly searching for [terms] to try and figure this out myself, or find a tutorial I could learn from. I'd very much appreciate suggestions on why an answer eluded me.

What are you doing there? You're indicating that you would have rather not *needed* to ask the question since you thought the answer had to be simple. That can go a long way toward thwarting the "did you even try?" mentality, while giving folks a better idea of where you are with the problem.

Now, about being welcomed? Yes, you got some down votes because folks thought that your question wasn't particularly useful, but [look at this answer you received](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045282/50049) - custom tailored by one of the *leading experts* in the field to help you learn, crafted as friendly as could be.

There is some validity to someone saying "You probably want to work through some tutorials first, then ask when you don't understand something about them" - but, yeah, that can be hard when you *honestly* don't know what words might make Google show you something relevant.

Still, I'd say .. you got a pretty welcoming response, and you now know quite a bit more about it than you did.

Comment: Finally someone human around here. Thank you, I was about to give up on this website. My respect for you sir, you showed me that you care, you understand and you explained to me what am I doing wrong instead of "watch your attitude kid" or "your question is demanding for code and it doesn't have ant relevance". Thank you once more. God bless you.

Comment: You're welcome Randi. You and Oded got off on the wrong foot, and then everyone got frustrated. He does offer a good take-away, which is the more you put _into_ asking, the more folks will try to help you get out of it. My advice is good for when you're _really_ stuck, and feeling even _more_ stuck each time you search. As long as you convey that, you'll probably do fine. Also last bit, if you're working through a tutorial series, it's nice to link to it so experts can see what the _tutorial_ was trying to teach you, and incorporate that into their answer as well.

Answer (score 16):

> then I wonder why is this site even here if that's the whole point

There you go. That's not the whole point.

We are trying to create a repository of **good** questions and answers, which we do by having a very specific Q&A format. This means there is a bunch of questions that are simply not suitable for our format.

Now, given that the people looking at questions to answer are volunteers - people who are not getting paid to support you, they tend to expect people to make an effort (search the web, search the site, try things out in code etc...) before posting questions. They expect questions to be formatted properly and use correct grammar and syntax.

In other words - questions that are deemed lazy or that ask too much (or are entirely off topic) will get downvotes.

---

I've gone and taken a look at your questions, after initially posting my thoughts.

And found that they are mostly phrased as "give me teh codes" - reading like you are expecting other people to do the basic, initial work you should be doing. The people who read those will downvote such posts.

You want your posts to not be downvoted? Make an effort. Write a legible question explaining what you tried and where you are still having problems.

Comment: I think that everyone makes an effort searching before posting a question.

Comment: Then why not indicate that in your question? People do not read minds.

Comment: Did I asked for the code ? I simply showed the error to the people and I've asked why does it happen. Just what I was saying. Newbie questions aren't allowed here. They should make a rule.

Comment: No @RandiRobert - questions that do not follow the quality guidelines of any member are not allowed - big difference

Comment: @RandiRobert hover over the downvote button and see the message which says "This question does not show any research effort..." Newbie questions, however are allowed.

Comment: Oh, ok next time I post something I'll post a log with my browser's history. Maybe after that it will show "research efforts".

Comment: @RandiRobert not necessary, instead, summarise what you have found and why it was not an adequate solution for your coding.

Comment: I've said that I was following a Bucky tutorial Gosh !!!

Comment: That is not showing in your question precisely why aspects are not helping you.

Comment: No need to be rude - to help improve your questions, describe in detail why aspects of the tutorial doesn't fully help in the project that you are doing.  Asking for debugging is off topic as per the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Your questions look not that bad (to me anyway - have not voted on them as yet).  There are some great examples of how to put together a great post.